# Issue installing GAE plugin to work with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jvm

I'm trying to make a Google App Engine App, but whenever I try to run the app, I get the following message:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Google App Engine Project Validator' on project 'ScalaWagsGameServer'.
Unable to locate the JVM for project ScalaWagsGameServer. Please verify that you have a project-level JVM installed by inspecting your project's build path.
Unable to locate the JVM for project ScalaWagsGameServer. Please verify that you have a project-level JVM installed by inspecting your project's build path.

I've tried installing a new JDK and JRE, but nothing has changed anything. I've been trying to set the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable as well, which is what I saw should be done on other Stack Overflow questions, but everything I change it to is said to be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

- Assuming that you have installed the JDK on your machine. Ensure that from the terminal or command prompt, you can access your JDK (javac, etc). Ensure the correct environment variables are setup.
- Inside of Eclipse, go to `Preferences->Java->Installed JREs` and validate if you have linked to the correct JDK or not. Most likely the list is empty here or its not linked to your installed JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I looked at the Installed JREs in Eclipse and I see that jre7 is installed. Is this what I need? Also, how do I access my JDK from the terminal and check the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the project was in the wrong directory.